# Can't consistently maximize WPF window

Tags: wpf

I have a minimized WPF window.  I click the item in the taskbar to maximize.  It makes a little audio ding, then I try again, and again.  Usually about the third try it will maximize.  What could cause it to refuse my initial maximize attempt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is that you have some code that's changing the value of the ResizeMode property to NoResize.

See this page for more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748948.aspx

Second, you might be overriding [OnStateChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.onstatechanged.aspx) and not calling base.OnStateChanged() consistently.

Third, you may have something hogging the UI's thread during your first attempts. Once that task--whatever it is--stops blocking then WPF can repaint the window in restored/maximized state.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when trying to manually maximize a custom window.
The solution was to put the next code in my maximize button...

```
this.SizeToContent = System.Windows.SizeToContent.Manual;
this.MaxWidth = double.PositiveInfinity;
this.MaxHeight = double.PositiveInfinity;
this.Width = double.NaN;
this.Height = double.NaN;
this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
```

Where 'this' referes to the Window.